# SQL view Aggregate function not pulling per row

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and am trying to create a view with an aggregate function which I will then query so I can get all the data points I need together.

I am looking at tables that contain:
Contacts table:

```
contactid 123
lastname  Overflow
firstname Stack
```

Calls table:

```
contactid 123 starttime 3/4/2013
contactid 123 starttime 2/2/2013
contactid 123 starttime 1/3/2013
```

I am attempting to create a view so I can get the max date (3/4/2013) along with contactid and name.  However, my query is pulling multiple starttimes for some reason.

This is how I'm creating the view:

```
Create VIEW LastIntakeView
AS SELECT c.contactid, c.lastname, c.firstname, ca.starttime
FROM sfcd.dbo.Contacts c, sfcd.dbo.Calls ca
WHERE ca.starttime=(select MAX(cl.starttime)
from sfcd.dbo.Calls cl where
ContactTypeID=29 group by cl.contactid);
```

I am getting this error message: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I've tried various ways to get the max date.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: [Please stop using antique `FROM a,b` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx). Also please specify the version of SQL Server you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery return more than 1 row to ca.StartTime, which is not acceptable for operator =, !=, <, <= , >, >=, it can be accepted by operator IN etc. 
But in your case, please try to **join your subquery return**.

```
Create VIEW LastIntakeView
AS 
SELECT c.contactid, 
       c.lastname, 
       c.firstname, 
       cl.Maxstarttime
FROM sfcd.dbo.Contacts c
left join (
        select Contactid, MAX(starttime) as MaxStartTime
        from sfcd.dbo.Calls 
        where ContactTypeID=29 
        group by contactid
        ) cl
on c.contactid = cl.contactid
```

Answer (score 1):

In the subquery you get all lines of table Calls with contactType 29. Thats not what you want I guess.

That should do it:

```
Create VIEW LastIntakeView AS 
SELECT c.contactid, c.lastname, c.firstname, MAX(ca.starttime) X
FROM sfcd.dbo.Contacts c left join sfcd.dbo.Calls ca on c.contactid = ca.contactid
where ca.ContactTypeID=29
group by c.contactid, c.lastname, c.firstname
```

Comment: I got this error on this but the other answer above worked.  I was not sure how to debug, unfortunately.  Thanks your help.  Msg 4511, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LastIntakeView1, Line 2
Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 4.